# FFmpeg performs every second task

Tags: video, shell, ffmpeg

Why does `ffmpeg` perform every second task that it is ordered to?

```
for i in *.MTS; do
     echo ffmpeg -i \"$i\" -c:a copy -c:v copy \"$i\" | sed 's/MTS/mp4/2'
done | sh
```

For example. if I have 9 MTS files like:

```
0001.MTS
0002.MTS
0003.MTS
0004.MTS
0005.MTS
0006.MTS
0007.MTS
0008.MTS
0009.MTS
```

This converts only `001 003 005 007 009`. Any reason for that? The same command without `| sh` prints proper set of orders. It becomes really a headache when you have 64 video files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, why only every second `ffmpeg` command is executed, I could not reproduce this on my machine. However, you approach is too complicated. A cleaner solution would be:

- for `bash` compatible shells:

  ```
  for i in *.MTS; do
    ffmpeg -i $i -c:a copy -c:v copy ${i%MTS}mp4
  done
  ```

  Please read about the `%` and related operators in the section *Parameter Expansion* in *bash*'s man page.
- for `csh` compatible shells:

  ```
  foreach i (*.MTS)
    ffmpeg -i $i -c:a copy -c:v copy $i:r.mp4
  end
  ```

  Here, the `:r` modifiers removes the file extension. Read more about some other *modifiers* in the (somewhat unintuitively) section *History substitution* of *tcsh*'s man page.

Comment: That works. It also works if I move `| sh` before `done`. But why does it work with defect if I pipe it altogether (`| sh` after `done`)?

Comment: @theoden: What shell and what flavor of `sh` do you use? (It works with e.g. dash 0.5.7).

Comment: for `sh` it's `bash 3.2.53` and for the parent shell it's `bash 4.3.39`.

Comment: @theoden: I don't have bash 3.x at hand, so I could not check if using that version I could reproduce this behavior. Sorry...

Comment: @mpv if you have bash 4.3.39, you can. I should've said that the latter throws the same error.